# how to Enable button if "All textfield" is not empty flutter

Tags: flutter

my app has two textformfield. I want to enable button if all textfield are not empty.
In the internet, there are a way to enable button if "one" textfield are not empty.
I try to make isFilledTitle true if title of textfield is not empty. and isFilledContent true if content of textfield is not empty. and then if they are all true, isButtonActive is true. but it doesn't work.

```
late TextEditingController _titleEditingController;
late TextEditingController _contentEditingController;
bool isButtonActive = true;
bool isFilledContent = false;
bool isFilledTitle = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _titleEditingController = TextEditingController();
    _contentEditingController = TextEditingController();

    _titleEditingController.addListener(() {
      final isFilledTitle = _titleEditingController.text.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() {
        this.isFilledTitle = isFilledTitle;
      });
    });

    _contentEditingController.addListener(() {
      final isFilledContent = _contentEditingController.text.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() {
        this.isFilledContent = isFilledContent;
      });
    });
    if(isFilledContent && isFilledTitle){
      setState(() {
        isButtonActive = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isButtonActive = false;
      });
    }
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      child: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBarWriteContainer(
                onButtonPressed: isButtonActive
                    ? (widget.postNo != null)
                        ? () => revisePost()
                        : () => newPost()
                    : null,
           ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah your answer is correct but the user needs validation on two text field so i will modify the answer like

```
 class _TempDialogState extends State<TempDialog> {
      final TextEditingController _inputController = TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _inputController2 = TextEditingController();
      bool enable = false;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _inputController.dispose();
        _inputController2.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _inputController,
                onChanged: (data) {
                  if (_inputController.text.isEmpty ||
                      _inputController2.text.isEmpty) {
                    enable = false;
                  } else {
                    enable = true;
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _inputController2,
                onChanged: (data) {
                  if (_inputController.text.isEmpty ||
                      _inputController2.text.isEmpty) {
                    enable = false;
                  } else {
                    enable = true;
                  }
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: enable ? () {} : null,
                child: Text('${enable}'),
              )
            ])),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any additional libraries to do that. Flutter has it out-of-the-box and you can make sure you're not going to rebuild the whole tree on each keystroke.

`TextEditingController` extends `ValueNotifier<TextEditingValue>` which means you can utilize `ValueListenableBuilder` from `material` package to listen to text changes.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _inputController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _inputController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      TextField(controller: _inputController),
      ValueListenableBuilder<TextEditingValue>(
        valueListenable: _inputController,
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: value.text.isNotEmpty ? () {} : null,
            child: Text('I am disabled when text is empty'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it works for just one textformfield, I want to enable button when all textformfield are not empty, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

You only set the `isButtonActive` in the `initState`. Try updating it in the controller listeners. Maybe something like:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _titleEditingController = TextEditingController();
    _contentEditingController = TextEditingController();

    _titleEditingController.addListener(() {
      final isFilledTitle = _titleEditingController.text.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() {
        this.isFilledTitle = isFilledTitle;
        updateIsButtonActive();
      });
    });

    _contentEditingController.addListener(() {
      final isFilledContent = _contentEditingController.text.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() {
        this.isFilledContent = isFilledContent;
        updateIsButtonActive();
      });
    });
  }

  void updateIsButtonActive() {
    if(isFilledContent && isFilledTitle){
      isButtonActive = true;
    } else {
      isButtonActive = false;
    }
  }
```